# MySQL Partitions & Frequently Moving Rows

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I am looking to partition on a datetime stamp that will used to show which data is most currently.

This will occur frequent movement of data between partitions.

- What issues if any will this create?
- Would if affect speed over time?
- Is changing a row from one partition to another just updating the partition indexes (thus not a big deal)?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning lets you split the physical file(s) representing the DB across multiple files. When you update a record and change one or more of the fields upon upon which the partitioning rules are based, the DB will be forced to physically move the updated records to the file under which its new partition values require it to be.

So using a timestamp would not be a good idea, because you'd be forcing a lot of extra overhead to keep "related" records together.

This will affect speed over time, because you'll be fragmenting the DB files as these records are shuffled around, plus the extra I/O overhead, updating indexes to reflect new locations, etc...

e.g. fields for partition calculations should essentially be treated as constants and left alone. Not to say you CAN'T do updates, but they shouldn't be FREQUENT updates.